# $x^3+y^3-3xy+C=0$ is a smooth curve for $C\neq0$ or $1$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Show that $x^3+y^3-3xy+C=0$ describes a smooth curve for $C\neq0$ and $C\neq1$.

For $C=0$, the curve self-intersects at the origin, so cannot be smooth. For $C=1$, the curve contains an isolated point at $(x,y)=(1,1)$. However, I'm not sure how to show that the curve is smooth for all other values of $C$.

I guess I'd be done if I could find some smooth parametrisation for the curve (that is injective and has non-zero derivative).

Comment: In general, it's hard and usually impossible to find an explicit parametrization. Have you learned the Implicit Function Theorem?

Comment: @TedShifrin yes I have. How does it apply here?

Comment: It tells you that if the gradient of the defining function vanishes nowhere on $C$, then locally near every point the curve $C$ is the graph of a smooth function.

Answer (score 2):

The singular points are characterized by the vanishing of both partial derivatives of the polynomial describing the curve. Since
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3x^2-3y,\qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=3y^2-3x
$$
they can both vanish only at a point where $x^4=x$.

For $x=0$, we have also $y=0$, which is not on the cubic unless $C=0$.

For $x=1$, we have $y=1$, which is not on the cubic unless $C=1$.

For $x=\omega$ (a complex cube root of $1$), we have $y=\omega^2$ and
$$
\omega^3+\omega^6-3\omega\omega^2+C=0
$$
if and only if $C=1$. Similarly for $x=\omega^2$ and $y=\omega^4=\omega$.

What about points at infinity? The homogeneous equation is $F(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3-3xyz+Cz^3$ and the partial derivatives are
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=3x^2-3yz,\qquad
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=3y^2-3yz,\qquad
\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}=-3xy+3Cz^2
$$
For $z=0$, we get $x=y=0$. So the improper points are not singular for any $C$.